# deployment failed at assets:precompile using capistrano gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-2.7

We are using ruby 2.7.3 and Rails 6.1.3.2 while deploying the application using Capistrano gem it throws below error -

```
INFO [4158d929] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.7.3@app-6 do bundle exec rake         assets:precompile on carbonite
DEBUG [4158d929] Command: cd /export/app/app_production/releases/20220103125501 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.7.3@app-6 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [4158d929] Yarn executable was not detected in the system
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
DEBUG [4158d929] Yarn executable was not detected in the system
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
DEBUG [4158d929] /export/app/app_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000

Here are the versions of yarn, node, and npm on server:

yarn -v 1.22.17
npm -v 6.14.15
node -v v14.18.2

Even yarn is installed globally.

yarn global list
yarn global v1.22.17
Done in 0.05s.
```

please give some suggestions.

Comment: Did you check that yarn, node and npm are available for "deployer" user (the user that you use to deploy on the remote server) and it shows its version in the application folder?

Comment: Yes. I have checked that yarn, node and npm are available for "deployer" user.

Comment: Please show the output of "which yarn" for the user under which you're deploying.

Comment: which yarn
/dir/app/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/yarn

Comment: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/3254 - Please check the link that solution work for me